# No reference fields in the node object that Contentful Rich Text receives from Gatsby and GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-plugin

I'm using Gatsby 5 and contentful/rich-text-react-renderer.

I have a ContentfulPost type that has some links to related types within the rich text.

I'm following the docs (from [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/how-to-use-the-contentful-rich-text-field-with-gatsby/) and [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/blog/rendering-linked-assets-entries-in-contentful/)), that say that I need to query them in GraphQL:

```
query MyQuery {
  allContentfulPost {
    nodes {
      body {
        references {
          ... on ContentfulAlbum {
            node_locale
            contentful_id
            __typename
            id
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And that works fine:

```
 "nodes": [
        {
          "body": {
            "references": [
              {},
              {
                "contentful_id": "2P4r0pD6zphEIiOaKEaprO",
                "__typename": "ContentfulAlbum",
                "id": "06305ddb-a3fa-5265-9a2a-3e43524d351e",
                "slug": "disorders"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
]
```

The docs then state that I should create a custom renderer and use some properties within `node.data.target` ([see "references" section)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/how-to-use-the-contentful-rich-text-field-with-gatsby/). These are the options I use:

```
const options2 = {
    renderNode: {
        [INLINES.ENTRY_HYPERLINK]: (node) => {
            console.log(node);

            return <></>;
        },
    },
};
```

However, the only fields I get in the logs are:

```
​
data: Object { target: {…} }
​​
target: Object { sys: {…} }
​​​
sys: Object { id: "2P4r0pD6zphEIiOaKEaprO", type: "Link", linkType: "Entry" }
```

So, no slug that I can use.

I've seen everywhere (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769299 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998008 ) that the solution is to clear the cache (using gatsby clear, for example). However, that doesn't work in my case.

My goal is to render links with a dynamic url (${locale}/music/${slug})

Comment: " However, the docs then state that I should create a custom renderer and use some properties within node.data.target. " 


Can you attach a link to this doc .

Comment: I've edited the original post.

Comment: I see you r quering ``allContentfulPosts.nodes.body`` where in the docs they r quering ``allContentfulPosts.nodes.richText`` , are the response the same for both .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: the plugin itself.

Instead of using `contentful/rich-text-react-renderer` I should use `gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text`. That one does indeed populate the node object with the query from GraphQL